# Пунктуационные ошибки

Tags: пунктуация

Где в предложении пунктуационная ошибка:

> Глубоко-глубоко  отражались в пруду
> берег и вечернее небо, и белые полоски
> облаков.

А у Бунина вот так: "Глубоко-глубоко отражались в пруде и берег, и вечернее небо, и белые полоски облаков".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Глубоко-глубоко отражались в пруду берег, и вечернее небо,и белые полоски облаков.

Если союз И повторяется хотя бы два раза, то и после первого однородного члена без союза также ставится запятая. Интонация в этом случае перечислительная.

Comment: Спасибо,не знал.Над такими случаями мы не работали ,зато сразу тест выполняй,да ещё и правильно!

Answer (score 0):

Глубоко-глубоко отражались в пруду берег и вечернее небо,и белые полоски облаков.

Comment: Где в предложении пунктуационная ошибка?